# Windows: pointer unicity

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I had a need of a quick unique ID in one of my classes to differenciate one process from another. I decided to use the address of the instance to do so. I ended up with something like this (`quintptr` is a Qt defined type of integer to store addresses with the correct size, according to the platform):

```
Foo::Foo()
: _id(reinterpret_cast<quintptr>(this))
{
 ...
}
```

The idea is to compare the output of two different processes of the same exe. On Vista (my dev machine) there's no problem. But on XP, the value of `_id` is the same (!) in the two processes.

Can anyone explain why is that? and if it's a good idea to use pointers like that (I thought so, I'm not so sure anymore)?

Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you just query the process id...? The location of the instance / pointer is going to depend on whether or not the operating system allocates a new address space to each process or not... and whether or not the order of execution for those process is the same... etc.. all of which you probably shouldn't care about in your process unless you're doing something very low level...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every process gets its own address space. On XP, they're all the same. Therefore it's very common to see what you saw: two objects that have the same address, but in two different address spaces.

It turns out that this contributes to security risks. Attackers were able to guess where vulnerable objects would be in memory, and exploit those. Vista randomizes address spaces (ASLR) which means that two processes are far more likely to put the same object at different addresses.

For your case, using pointers like that is not a smart idea. Just use the process ID

Comment: Ok, thanks. `QProcess::pid()` seem to be useflu when starting an external process. How to get the PID of the current runnig app?

Answer (score 3):

The reason is each process has its own address space and if two processes do the same they just use the same virtual addresses - maybe even heap allocations will be done at same virtual addresses.

You could call `GetCurrentProcessId()` once and store the result somewhere so that further retrieval is very fast. The process id persists and is unique for the lifetime of the process.

Comment: +1 While the question is tagged with [windows], as Qt is already been used, it might be better to use Qt libraries to abstract the windows only call into something that will work if at a later time he decides that multiplatform does not only mean different windows.

Answer (score 1):

Each process gets its own address space. Unless something like  [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) kicks in, the memory layouts of two processes stemming from the same executable are likely to be very similar, if not identical.

So your idea is not a good one. Using the process ID sounds like a saner approach here, but keep in mind that those can be recycled too.